# JPA generating PK that always starts with the same String and then continues with GenerateValue

Tags: postgresql, jpa, java-8, persistence

Basically what i need is for my PK to always start with a String (let's say it will always start with "JPA-", and then to continue with value from `GenerateValue`. So basically the objects will have PKs such as JPA-1, JPA-2, JPA-3.

I can't use `@GenericGenerator` because it isn't included in JPA and `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` or `TABLE` didn't work.

Comment: Custom sequence value generation isn't covered by JPA, so it isn't clear what you are looking for. You will have to resort to a JPA provider specific sequence generator that takes a sequence number and adds a String prefix, or you do it yourself in a prePersist event - but you'll have to look up the numeric sequence value yourself.

Comment: If it is truly constant then *get rid of it*, you can append it on select `(select 'JPA-' || ltrim(to_char(<seq> , '9999999999'))`  . If it can contain other values (now or in the future) then create a `prefix` column, then essentially do the same  `(select ' <prefix>  || ltrim(to_char(<seq> , '9999999999'))` . Going a step further, create a `view` that handles the constant/prefix.